# How to recognize an update from XUL to Jetpack?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xul

We're updating our Firefox add-on. The current one the users have is built using the old XUL technology, the new extension is built with Jetpack (add-on SDK). Is there a way to tell that a XUL add-on was installed prior to the Jetpack one (they have the same ID)?

In other words, we need to trigger an update event when add-on changes from XUL to the newer Jetpack version. Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` function has an argument.

```
exports.main(reason) {
    console.log('reason:', reason);

}
```

The reasons are:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions#Reason_constants

Comment: It's not valid JavaScript and I get an exception when trying to run it with Firefox: `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`. Maybe we need to add a function? (you can't write a function without the word "function"). And where is the `main` function? We have `main.js` but not a `main` function.